# how to restart counting in excel after meeting specific value

Tags: excel

In the below image I want to repeat the counting after it reaches 100 in a cell or shows zero and again starts from 20.i.e based on quantity.

If I give 1 in the D column then it multiplies 1*20 and gives 20 In the E column. similarly, it continues but when it reaches 100 it should rest or start counting from 20 from the next cell plz help me.

[image]

Comment: What if QTY is 5+?

Answer (score 1):

I think I need some more information on column E's formula.  It looks like you are not just multiplying column D by 20 to get column E, because 1*20 doesn't ever equal 40 or 60 or 80.

My guess is that your formula for column E is, for example:
`=D3*20 + E2`, or in other words, multiply 1*20 and add the previous cell from column E.

If that's what you're doing, then try the below formula, which changes how a cell in column E is populated depending on what the value of the previous cell is:
`=IF(E2<>80,D3*20+D2,0)`

You'll need to set that formula in E3.

Answer (score 0):

These are the formulas you need:-

```
[E2] =MOD(SUM(D$1:D2)*20,100)
[F2] =IF(E2=0,"PAY","PAID")
```

Copy both down as far as you require.